# get progress of a file being uploaded - unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix

i have a requirement to monitor the progress of a file being uploaded using script. In putty(software) we can view the Percentage Uplaod, Bytes transferred , Upload Speed and ETA in the right hand side. I want to develop a similar functionality. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is lacking any information of *how* your file is transferred. Most clients have some way to display progress, but that is depending on the individual client used (scp, sftp, ncftp, ...).

But there is a way to monitor progress independently on *what* is progressing: [`pv` (pipe viewer)](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml).

This tool has the sole purpose of *generating* monitoring information. It can be used in a way much similar to `cat`. You either use it to "lift" a file to `pv`'s stdout....

```
pv -petar <file> | ...
```

...or you use it in the middle of a pipe -- but you need to manually provide the "expected size" in order to get a proper progress bar, since `pv` cannot determine the size of the transfer beforehand. I used 2 Gigabyte expected size here (`-s 2G`)...

```
cat <file> | pv -petar -s 2G | ...
```

The options used are `-p` (progress bar), `-e` (ETA), `-t` (elapsed time), `-a` (average rate), and `-r` (current rate). Together they make for a nice mnemonic.

Other nice options:

- `-L`, which can be used to limit the maximum rate in the pipe (throttle).
- `-W`, to make `pv` wait until data is actually transferred before showing a progress bar (e.g. if the tool you are piping the data to will require a password first).

**This is most likely not what you're looking for (since chances are the transfer client you're using has its own options for showing progress)**, but it's the one tool I know that could work for virtually *any* kind of data transfer, and it might help others visiting this question in the future.